# JWT Express API not seeing HTTPInterceptor auth header

Tags: node.js, angular, express, jwt

I have the following implementation of JWT Middleware in ExpressJS

```
const authenticateJWT = (req, res, next) => {
  const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
  ...    
};
```

and this HTTPInterceptor implementation in Angular:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: { Authorization: 'Bearer ...' }
        });

        return next.handle(request);
    }
```

if I console.log the request variable in the interceptor I can see that the authorization header is successfully added but then in the JWT middleware it's undefined.
What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your interceptor:

```
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        let headers = request.headers;
        headers = headers.append("Authorization", 'Bearer ...');
        
        request = request.clone({
            headers: headers
        });

        return next.handle(request);
    }
```